# How to find max, min, mean, 5th,10th Percentile for all the variables in the dataset in r

Tags: r, summary

How to find max, min, mean, 5th,10th Percentile for all the variables in the dataset. Functions `colMax()` and `colMin()` are not working in my R(version 3.5), `apply(dat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) min(x, na.rm=TRUE))` and `apply(dat,2,min, na.rm=TRUE)` are not giving correct results for all variables(giving correct results for some variables(Columns)) when I cross verified with `min(dat$col1 ,na.rm=TRUE)`. using `colMeans(dat, na.rm=TRUE)` for finding mean but my dat(File-name) contains charater type variables, Now need to find mean for only numeric variables by neglecting charater variables. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this could help:

```
#Sample data
data("iris")
iris
Data <- iris[,-5]
#Compute
compute <- function(x)
{
  max <- max(x, na.rm=T)
  min <- min(x, na.rm=T)
  meanv <- mean(x, na.rm=T)
  q5 <- quantile(x, 0.05)
  q10 <- quantile(x, 0.10)
  ent <- data.frame(max=max, min=min, meanv=meanv, q5=q5, q10=10)
  rownames(ent) <- NULL
  return(ent)
}
apply(Data, 2, compute)
```

Comment: With the above code I had made a slight modification as `ent <- c(mini,maxi,meanv,q5,q10)` and neglecting to remove column names, worked better....Thanks a lot